# Google Sheets new sheet templating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like every new added sheet (when user presses "+" in lower left corner) to contain some templated information (headers for table). I'm not talking about whole document template, I'd like to make it only for one document. Now for that purpose I use special sheet with template and just duplicate it.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you used a script to duplicate your document template, therefore your new sheet will have the template information by default. What do you think?

Comment: for example you can create a macro button, and when you click on it, it will automatically generate a new sheet according to the provided template. Would you like that instead?

Comment: @MariosKaramanis yes, I would like it and I'll definitely do it if never find the way with built-in "+" button.

Comment: please share with us a screenshot of this template? how can we build that for you if we don't know what the template looks like?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*While you can't create 'template' sheets to copy from, you can use the `onChange()` trigger to insert the template to the new sheet as soon as it has been added.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events), there exists a `changeType` value in the event object that is generated when the structure of a Spreadsheet is changed:

> **changeType** The type of change (`EDIT`, `INSERT_ROW`, `INSERT_COLUMN`, `REMOVE_ROW`, `REMOVE_COLUMN`, `INSERT_GRID`, `REMOVE_GRID`, `FORMAT`, or `OTHER`).

The `INSERT_GRID` value can be used to execute some code when a new sheet is added.

#### Code Example:

For this example, I will assume that you have a template sheet from which you can copy the templated information from, and for this example I will assume it is called `Template`.

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

function saveSheetNames() {
  var names = sheets.map(x => x.getName());
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("sheets", names.toString())
}

function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_GRID") {
    var rangeToCopy = templateSheet.getDataRange();
    var oldSheets = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("sheets").split(",");
    var names = sheets.map(x => x.getName());

    names.forEach(function(name) {
      if (oldSheets.indexOf(name) == -1) {
        rangeToCopy.copyTo(ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange(1, 1, rangeToCopy.getNumRows(), rangeToCopy.getNumColumns()));    
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("sheets", names.toString());
      }
    });    
  }
}
```

#### Set up:

The first thing you need to do, after inserting this script into your script editor, is run the function `saveSheetNames()`. This stores the current sheet names to the script's properties so that when you add a new sheet later, the new sheet can be determined.

Next, you will need to set up an `onChange` installable trigger.

Follow the `Edit > Current project's triggers` menu item, and you will have a new page open in the G Suite Developer Hub. Click the `+ Add Trigger` button in the bottom right and set up the trigger settings as follows:

- Choose which function to run: `onChange`
- Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
- Select event source: `From spreadsheet`
- Select event type: `On change`

And press save.

Now, when you add a new sheet with the default `+` button in the UI, the `onChange()` function will run, and copy the template sheet to the new sheet. It might take a couple of seconds, but it will be done automatically.

#### References:

- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)